# sqlAlchemy jsonb in Django form

Tags: python, json, django, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I have a PostgreSQL database and use sqlAlchemy to access the data. In one of the tables, I have a JSONb column. When I load a sqlAlchemy object (an entry from the DB) containing a not empty JSON entry sqlAlchemy will directly transfer it to a Python `dict`. On default, for Python `dict`s single quotes are used; therefore, even though JSON uses double quotes, the `dict` is with single quotes. I then show the JSON in a Django form field so that a user might update the JSON and/or other parameters. When I get the form back with the content of the JSON field as an `str`, I want to validate that the user sends a valid JSON, so I execute `json.loads(json_form_field_content)` to verify it. This will raise an error if single quotes are in the JSON string. This is especially bad as this will even happen if the user has not changed the JSON.

I googled hard and didn't find a fitting solution for my problem, so I thought hard and came up with an in my option poor solution.

I use the following code to transfer the `dict` to a string where I explicitly set double quotes for strings.

```py
curly_br_open = "{"
curly_br_close = "}"


def replace_double_with_single_quotes(item):
    if isinstance(item, str):
        return f'"{item}"'
    if isinstance(item, dict):
        item_list = []
        for key, value in the item.items():
            item_list.append(
                f"{replace_double_with_single_quotes(key)}:"
                f"{replace_double_with_single_quotes(value)}"
            )
        item_str = ",".join(item_list)
        return f"{curly_br_open}{item_str}{curly_br_close}"
    if isinstance(item, list):
        item_list = []
        for value in an item:
            item_list.append(replace_double_with_single_quotes(value))
        item_str = ",".join(item_list)
        return f"[{item_str}]"
    else:
        raise ValueError(f"{item} is not parsable as a valid json string.")
```

This code is not bulletproof as it, for example, allows for not hashable types (`list`s and `dict`s) to be keys in `dict`s, but I will execute this code on the `dict` I get from the database, so I expect a valid JSON.

I can not simply cast the `dict` as an `str` and replace all single with double quotes, as some strings might have a single quote.

I will execute the code above on the JSON before I send it to the Django form.

My question is whether there is a better solution than manually transferring the `dict` to a string. I would also be open to taking action somewhere else in my process. I was uncomfortable manipulating the JSONb class of sqlAlchemy to return a string instead of a dict as I didn't want to break anything. I also thought it best to manipulate the JSON before sending it to the user and not after I get it back, as I have a more controllable environment.